# How do I display Search API Facets and Openlayers Proximity search in one view?

Tags: 7, views, search, javascript

I am trying to add search facets to a specific views page that uses the openlayer proximity filter. So far I can only show facets in a view if I create a new view showing the search index I created in the search api.

If I chose to show 'node' or anything else other than a search api index, no facets will show up.

Now I am using openlayers proximity filter. This option again is only available if I chose show 'node' when creating a new view.[image]

How do I get to display both my facets as well as the proximity filter in a view?

Comment: Ok, so according to this http://drupal.org/node/1235026 one can do it using the facet block display in views. Can anyone provide an example for this, please?

Answer (score 1):

The "facets block" type that drunken monkey mentions on the issue you link to, is simply a type of views "Display", you can see below where you add one:
[image: Search API Facet block]
I haven't used the proximity filter, nor much of Search API, so I can't really give you an answer with better details. It seems to be like drunken monkey has actually answered the question in the issue queue, and perhaps you need to specify more precisely where you have a problem, to get better help.